# Installing fontcustom on centos 7 returns error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I try to install font custom tool for generating font icons from svg.
When I try to use `sudo gem install fontcustom` on my cento7 machine I get the error:

```
ERROR:  Error installing fontcustom:
    ruby_dep requires Ruby version >= 2.2.5, ~> 2.2.
```

But my ruby version is 2.2.6.

`ruby --version
 ruby 2.2.6p396 (2016-11-15 revision 56800) [x86_64-linux]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to install fontcustom gem on linux machine you need to do:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev fontforge

wget http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip

unzip woff-code-latest.zip -d sfnt2woff && cd sfnt2woff && make && sudo mv sfnt2woff /usr/local/bin/

git clone --recursive https://github.com/google/woff2.git && cd woff2 && make clean all && sudo mv woff2_compress /usr/local/bin/ && sudo mv woff2_decompress /usr/local/bin/

gem install fontcustom
```

Here is complete guide for installation of `fontcustom` gem:

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/fontcustom/2.0.0

Comment: wget http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip
--2017-08-11 16:31:02--  http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip
Resolving people.mozilla.com (people.mozilla.com)... 63.245.214.133
Connecting to people.mozilla.com (people.mozilla.com)|63.245.214.133|:80... failed: Connection refused.

Comment: http://people.mozilla.com/~jkew/woff/woff-code-latest.zip link not exist

Comment: I have update the answer please take a look at url, and you can upvote me now :-)

Answer (score 0):

Before installing fontcustome gem to Linux you need to install some dependencies. the complete guide can be found on.

https://github.com/FontCustom/fontcustom